# Null pointer exception when access index of a DefaultListModel

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, defaultlistmodel

I have a list:

```
JList characterList = new JList(characterListModel);
characterListModel = new DefaultListModel();        
String myCharacters[]={"Dean Winchester","Sam Winchester",
            "Bobby Singer","Castiel"};
for (String myCharacter : myCharacters) {
        ((DefaultListModel) characterList.getModel()).addElement(myCharacter);  
}
```

And I've written a method, *in a seperate class*, to remove a character at a selected index:

```
public void removeCharacter() {
    DefaultListModel characterListModel = ((PlayerContentPane) IViewManager.Util.getInstance()
        .getMyContainerPane().getMyPlayerManagerPane().getContentPane())
        .getCharacterListModel();
    JList characterList = ((PlayerContentPane) IViewManager.Util.getInstance()
        .getMyContainerPane().getMyPlayerManagerPane().getContentPane())
        .getCharacterList();
    int idx = characterList.getSelectedIndex(); //<---line 62
    int size = characterListModel.getSize();
    characterListModel.remove(idx);
    if (size == 0) { 
        //do nothing
    } else { 
        if (idx == characterListModel.getSize()) {
            idx--;
        }

        characterList.setSelectedIndex(idx);
        characterList.ensureIndexIsVisible(idx);
    }

}
```

However when I run it with my button, I get this stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.detica.LarpDB.Controller.Controller.removeCharacter(Controller.java:62)
at com.detica.LarpDB.view.PlayerContentPane$3.actionPerformed(PlayerContentPane.java:94)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

A lot of the issues I've seen googling this, stem from the line: `DefaultListModel characterListModel = ....`
And the issue they have is that their creating a `new` instance of the object, now I''m only new to this whole Java thing, but this shouldn't be an issue with me, as I've not made anythign new, I've just been specific about which object this is.

Please could someone help me untangle myself?

Comment: You should, at minimum, make a variable reference to your PlayerContentPane object so you don't have to keep doing `((PlayerContentPane) IViewManager.Util.getInstance().getMyContainerPane().getMyPlayerManagerPane().getContentPane())`....

Comment: Yeah, it's a lot easier, I think to make any components that you need to access class variables, like in this case make characterList a class variable, so you just have it and don't need to keep finding it.

Comment: Just to save a little trouble: Rather than creating an instance of the default model and then adding all the elements of an array to that model, why not just create the list using the constructor that takes an array?

Comment: @Jay, The removeCharacter method is elsewhere so I need some way of accessing it from outside that class. Also this is just a place holder whilst I sort out my program.

Comment: So make characterList a class variable, and make it public, or if you're of the school that objects to public variables, provide a public accessor for it.

Comment: @Jay I do, thats what `.getCharacterList();` is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those 2 lines can create a lot of problems:

```
DefaultListModel characterListModel = ((PlayerContentPane) IViewManager.Util.getInstance()
    .getMyContainerPane().getMyPlayerManagerPane().getContentPane())
    .getCharacterListModel();
JList characterList = ((PlayerContentPane) IViewManager.Util.getInstance()
    .getMyContainerPane().getMyPlayerManagerPane().getContentPane())
    .getCharacterList();
```

If any of the chained methods return `null` (for whatever reason) the line will throw a NullPointerException.

I suggest you break them down in several lines and check the value of each call to see where you get the `null` from.

**EDIT**

Just realised that line 62 is `int idx = characterList.getSelectedIndex();`. It means that `characterList` is null.

Comment: @Pureferret See my edit - if you get a NPE on that line, it means `characterList` is null.

Comment: I pinned it down to the list, and then I removed `JList` from `JList characterList = new JList(characterListModel);`. Any Idea why that would work?

Comment: I have not seen your code so I can only guess. `Jlist characterList = new ...` creates a new local variable called `characterList`. If your class also has a member called `characterList`, this local variable will hide the class member which will keep its default value (in this case: null) and `getCharacterList()` returns that value. By removing `JList` in the statement, you allocated the new list to the class member instead of the local variable and your code now works as expected.

Comment: That's exactly what I think is happening.

Answer (score 2):

If it's failing on the line that you indicated is line 62, then the only object referenced on that line, and therefore the only thing that could be null, is characterList. This implies that your getCharacterList function is returning null. (If the error was inside the getSelectedIndex function, then you would have another line in your stack trace.)

As you didn't post the getCharacterList function, I can't say much more. But you should take a look at that function and see under what circumstances it could return null.

Comment: It could only return null if the list was null.

Comment: The code is something like `return CharacterList`, I'm not sure how that could have a bug.

Comment: Then the variable CharacterList is not being properly set. As I say, without seeing more relevant code, I can only shoot in the dark.

Comment: Considering I've fixed the issue, I don't think this warrants further discussion unfortunately.